# Menu entry not shown on Mac OS

Tags: python, linux, macos, pyqt

I'm trying to port my PyQt program to Mac OS. I developed it on Linux.

PyQt (4) is installed on the 2 computers, with python 3.4. Everything seems to work. The program works perfectly on the Linux computer. I simply transfered it to the mac computer, and tried to run it. And it runs, except for only ONE thing:

I have a menu entry (in the menu bar), for the settings of the program:

```
# Action to show a settings window
self.settingsAction = QtGui.QAction('Settings', self)
self.settingsAction.triggered.connect(lambda: Settings(self))

...Some code...

# Menu entry for the settings
self.menubar.addAction(self.settingsAction)
```

On Linux, the 'Settings' entry is perfectly displayed in the menu bar, and opens the settings window. On Mac OS however, the Settings entry is not displayed. Simply not displayed. All the other entries (Files, Edit, View, etc) are displayed correctly, but not Settings. And there is no exception raised.

I'm stuck here, I never used Mac OS, so I don't even know where to start for debugging.

Do you have any suggestion ?

EDIT:

I also tried

# Action to show a settings window
    self.settingsAction = QtGui.QAction('Preferences', self)
    self.settingsAction.triggered.connect(lambda: Settings(self))

```
...Some code...

# Menu entry for the settings
self.menubar.addAction(self.settingsAction)
```

Comment: Maybe, the cause is that the menubar of every app is displayed at the top of the screen in OS X.

Comment: What happed if you type `cmd` + `,` ?

Comment: @1Darco1, yes I know, but it's not that. Thomas, what do you mean ?

Comment: In Mac Os the setting entry is displayed in the `Application name` menu. (This shortcut will call the settings if present)

Comment: The menu on Mac OS has some peculiar behaviour. I'm not sure if you can add QActions like that to the Mac OS menubar; you might need to make an actual list for it, like the File and Edit menus, and have only one item in it. In addition, as @Thomas mentions, on Mac OS X, the preferences/settings menu is in a different location.

Comment: The Mac has "peculiar" request of "settings", so the 1st choice is not using settings but "Preferences", besides "settings", there are also "about" and "quit" has special meanings. So don't name the action like these values, use "Preferences", "Help" or "xyz quit" instead. You can check the Chrome menu, it already has these actions renamed.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I couldn't access a mac. So cmd +, did nothing, nothing happened. And I don't have any "Application Menu", just "Python" and my other normal menus. But I assume it's because I start the program from cli. I also tried to change "Settings" to preferences, but it changed nothing (see my edited question).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Macs have strange behavior regarding menu bars. Remember that mac menubars are displayed in the system menubar at the very top, not in the window like on a Windows or Linux machine. One solution is to use a non-native menubar so it appears in the window similar to a Windows or Linux machine.

```
menubar = self.menuBar()
menubar.setNativeMenuBar(False)
```

Also, when using PyQt on a mac, the system will intercept certain commands contain the word 'Quit', 'Exit', 'Setting', 'Settings', 'preferences' and probably a slew of others, and remove them from your menubar because they are reserved labels. if a menubar header has no items, it will not display, making it appear as if you haven't modified the menubar.

```
#exit = QtGui.QAction( 'Exit', self ) #this fails on my system
exit = QtGui.QAction( 'SomethingElse', self ) #this displays on my system
menubar = self.menuBar()
fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&File')
fileMenu.addAction(exit)
```

I found the 'Exit' information here: http://python.6.x6.nabble.com/addAction-to-menubar-td1916296.html

Also, calling raise_() doesn't change the menubar on my mac (Mavericks). I have to manually select the window (by clicking elsewhere then reclicking the window) to get the correct menubar to show for my pyqt app.

I hope this helps anyone else with these problems.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Greg. I want to add that on Mac, a menu must have at least one action, otherwise it will not show. Below is effects on Mac
[image]